# readline wrapper for Rust

Tags: c, rust, readline

I have tried to create a small readline wrapper for Rust, however, it does not work - I have tried to expose the functionality to free and remove history items, as well as to write history to a file. Nothing happens when I call the functions, i.e., the entries I wanted to delete are still there. Write to file function does not work too, the file is not even being created or modified.

Here's what I've done:

```
use errno::errno;
use libc::c_void;
use std::{ffi::CString, fmt, path::Path, ptr};

mod ext_readline {
    use libc::{c_char, c_int, c_void};

    #[repr(C)]
    pub struct HistoryEntry {
        pub line: *const c_char,
        pub data: *mut c_void,
    }

    #[link(name = "readline")]
    extern "C" {
        pub fn remove_history(which: c_int) -> *mut HistoryEntry;
        pub fn free_history_entry(entry: *mut HistoryEntry) -> *mut c_void;
        pub fn write_history(file: *const c_char) -> c_int;
    }
}

pub fn remove<'a>(offset: i32) -> &'a mut ext_readline::HistoryEntry {
    unsafe { &mut *ext_readline::remove_history(offset) }
}
pub fn free_entry(entry: &mut ext_readline::HistoryEntry) -> Result<(), *mut c_void> {
    unsafe {
        let data_ptr = ext_readline::free_history_entry(entry);

        if data_ptr.is_null() {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(data_ptr)
        }
    }
}

pub fn write(path: Option<&Path>) -> Result<i32, HistoryError> {
    with_path_ptr(path, |ptr| unsafe {
        gen_result(ext_readline::write_history(ptr))
    })
}

fn with_path_ptr<F>(path: Option<&Path>, f: F) -> Result<i32, HistoryError>
where
    F: Fn(*const i8) -> Result<i32, HistoryError>,
{
    if let Some(p) = path {
        match p.to_str() {
            Some(p) => {
                if let Ok(cs) = CString::new(p) {
                    return f(cs.as_ptr());
                }
            }
            None => {
                return Err(HistoryError::new(
                    "History Error",
                    "Unable to determine path!",
                ))
            }
        }
    }
    f(ptr::null())
}

fn gen_result(res: i32) -> Result<i32, HistoryError> {
    if res == 0 {
        Ok(res)
    } else {
        let e = errno();
        let code = e.0 as i32;
        let out = format!("Error {}: {}", code, e);
        Err(HistoryError::new("History Error", &out[..]))
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
/// Represents an error that has occurred within the History API.
pub struct HistoryError {
    desc: String,
    detail: String,
}

impl HistoryError {
    /// Create a HistoryError struct from the given description and detail.
    pub fn new<T>(desc: &str, detail: T) -> HistoryError
    where
        T: fmt::Display,
    {
        HistoryError {
            desc: String::from(desc),
            detail: format!("{}", detail),
        }
    }
}

/// Implemented as 'self.desc: self.detail'.
impl fmt::Display for HistoryError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}: {}", self.desc, self.detail)
    }
}

impl From<::std::ffi::NulError> for HistoryError {
    fn from(e: ::std::ffi::NulError) -> HistoryError {
        HistoryError::new("NulError", e)
    }
}

impl From<::std::str::Utf8Error> for HistoryError {
    fn from(e: ::std::str::Utf8Error) -> HistoryError {
        HistoryError::new("FromUtf8Error", e)
    }
}

impl From<::std::num::ParseIntError> for HistoryError {
    fn from(e: ::std::num::ParseIntError) -> HistoryError {
        HistoryError::new("ParseIntError", e)
    }
}
```

How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: How are you driving this code, can you add a minimum example? I tried your code with a couple of added functions to add history entries and print them out, and your code seems to work fine, the history file is also created: https://gist.github.com/c7c5b19ff1c3866424e94e94ae350e63  (I moved historyerror to another file to minimize the code discussed)

Comment: Well, for one, I'm not adding entries to history. I'm only deleting them. I also tried to load history from a temp filtered file, then save that, but that did not work too. Could that be the issue? https://gist.github.com/adder46/a28f6be9cc3003a84df6ac8850568ad8